# How to build WOPI validation application

Tags: validation, onenote, ms-wopi

http://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_test_ship/validator.html
As per this documentation, we need to build some HTML host page.

In this document, they mention one point that I didn't understand completely

> The simplest way to use the validation application is to use the view
>   action. To use the view action hosts should treat .wopitest files the
>   same way other Office documents are treated. In other words, hosts
>   should do the following:
>
> Launch a host page pointed at the .wopitest file. Ideally, this should
>   be the same host page used to host regular Office Online sessions.
>   This will allow the validation application to test things like
>   PostMessage and do some validation on the way the Office Online iframe
>   was loaded.

What is .wopitest file and what I need to do exactly, Can anyone please guide me ? please explain stepwise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They mean that you have to call that action in the same way you call any other action (looking for the action url in the discovery, etc.).
For example, when you want to open a .docx for view, you look into the discovery.xml and you find that you have to call https://word-view.officeapps-df.live.com/wv/wordviewerframe.aspx?", and of course you must have ready the Rest services for that action (checkFileInfo, etc.) and the WOPISrc pointing to a file that in fact is a .docx . Well, for the validation application is exactly the same, but you should call to WopiTest app instead of Word app (inside the discovery) and your generated WOPISrc should point to a file called "xxxx.wopitest" instead "xxxx.docx". That's it! ;)